# Android objeto Parcelable al volver pierde su valor

Tags: java, android, android-listview, objeto

esperando estén bien, tengo una inquietud.

Tengo dos actividades 1) Listado de cursos y sus hijos son las actividades - 2) Datos y evaluación de la actividad del curso

El proceso es el siguiente.

Selecciono una actividad del curso desde un **ExpandableListView** el cual con la posición del grupo y su hijo obtengo el objeto **Actividad**, previamente llenado. Este lo paso a la actividad (2) con un intent.

Hasta acá todo bien, mi problema es al evaluar la actividad. El cambio en la base de datos es correcto pero cuando hago el **set** en el objeto **actividad**, dentro de la actividad (2) el valor se mantiene, pero al volver atrás el valor se pierde, ya que no actualiza una imagen que tengo en el listado de actividades del **ExpandableListView**

Clase Actividad

```
class Activity implements Parcelable{
private Integer id;
private String titlePref;
private String title;
private String teacher;
private String type = "";
private Integer evaluateContent = 0;
private Integer evaluateTeacher = 0;
private Integer canEvaluate = 0;
private Integer isAccomplished = 0;
private Integer isBlocked = 0;
private Integer hvVideo = 0;
private Video videoObj = null;
private String bannerUrl = "";
private String blockName = "";

//default constructor, for video or other who extends of Activity
public Activity(Integer id) { this.setId(id); }
public Activity(Integer id, String titlePref, String title, String teacher, Integer isAccomplished, Integer isBlocked, Integer hvVideo, String bannerUrl, String blockName)
{
    this.setId(id);
    this.setTitlePref(titlePref);
    this.setTitle(title);
    this.setTeacher(teacher);
    this.setIsAccomplished(isAccomplished);
    this.setIsBlocked(isBlocked);
    this.setHvVideo(hvVideo);
    this.setBannerUrl(bannerUrl);
    this.setBlockName(blockName);
}

private Activity(Parcel in)
{
    id              = in.readInt();
    titlePref       = in.readString();
    title           = in.readString();
    teacher         = in.readString();
    canEvaluate     = in.readInt();
    evaluateContent = in.readInt();
    evaluateTeacher = in.readInt();
    isAccomplished  = in.readInt();
    isBlocked       = in.readInt();
    hvVideo         = in.readInt();
    bannerUrl       = in.readString();
    blockName       = in.readString();
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Activity> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Activity>()
{
    @Override
    public Activity createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Activity(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Activity[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Activity[size];
    }
};

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
{
    dest.writeInt(id);
    dest.writeString(titlePref);
    dest.writeString(title);
    dest.writeString(teacher);
    dest.writeInt(canEvaluate);
    dest.writeInt(evaluateContent);
    dest.writeInt(evaluateTeacher);
    dest.writeInt(isAccomplished);
    dest.writeInt(isBlocked);
    dest.writeInt(hvVideo);
    dest.writeString(bannerUrl);
    dest.writeString(blockName);
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitlePref() {
    return titlePref;
}

public void setTitlePref(String titlePref) {
    this.titlePref = titlePref;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getTeacher() {
    return teacher;
}

public void setTeacher(String teacher) {
    this.teacher = teacher;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public Integer getEvaluateContent() {
    return evaluateContent;
}

public void setEvaluateContent(Integer evaluateContent) {
    this.evaluateContent = evaluateContent;
}

public Integer getEvaluateTeacher() {
    return evaluateTeacher;
}

public void setEvaluateTeacher(Integer evaluateTeacher) {
    this.evaluateTeacher = evaluateTeacher;
}

public Integer getCanEvaluate() {
    return canEvaluate;
}

public void setCanEvaluate(Integer canEvaluate) {
    this.canEvaluate = canEvaluate;
}

public Integer getIsAccomplished() {
    return isAccomplished;
}

public void setIsAccomplished(Integer isAccomplished) {
    this.isAccomplished = isAccomplished;
}

public Integer getIsBlocked() {
    return isBlocked;
}

public void setIsBlocked(Integer isBlocked) {
    this.isBlocked = isBlocked;
}

public Integer getHvVideo() {
    return hvVideo;
}

public void setHvVideo(Integer hvVideo) {
    this.hvVideo = hvVideo;
}

public Video getVideoObj() {
    return videoObj;
}

public void setVideoObj(Video videoObj) {
    this.videoObj = videoObj;
}

public String getBannerUrl() {
    return bannerUrl;
}

public void setBannerUrl(String bannerUrl) {
    this.bannerUrl = bannerUrl;
}

public String getBlockName() {
    return blockName;
}

public void setBlockName(String blockName) {
    this.blockName = blockName;
}

public Video getVideo()
{
    return videoObj;
}
public Video makeVideo(String video){ return videoObj = new Video(this.getId(), video);}
```

Así paso el objeto a la otra actividad android (2):

```
listViewMyCoursesBlocks.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
        {
            myActivity = (Activity)parent.getExpandableListAdapter().getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
            if( myActivity.getIsBlocked() == 0 )
            {
                gPosition = groupPosition;
                cPosition = childPosition;
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyClassActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("myActivity", myActivity);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            }
            return  false;
        };
    });
```

Lo recibo así:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
myActivity = i.getExtras().getParcelable("myActivity");
```

Hago el set así:

```
myActivity.setEvaluateTeacher(3);
```

Al volver a la actividad (1):

En mi onResume quería actualizar una imagen del ExpandableListView que indica que esa actividad del curso esta "evaluada".

pero al hacer

```
myActivity.getEvaluateTeacher();
```

Devuelve como valor 0

Estuve leyendo y al parecer en JAVA no funciona pasar un valor por referencia, sino por valor. Entonces cada objeto debiera tener valor en su propia "Actividad android", si no entendi mal.

Como puedo setear un valor en mi actividad (2) y al volver a la actividad (1) pueda recibir el valor que le di .... y hacer algo como:

```
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Para que actualice la imagen del listado.

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final como nadie me ayudo jaja, no broma. Encontré la respuesta, aunque por lo que entendí hay un par de maneras para resolverlo.

Sin profundizar mucho, el problema de pasar un objecto de un Actividad a otra (1) a (2), es que se pasan por "valor" y no por "referencia". Es como si tuvieras duplicado el **objeto** y si puedes setear nuevos valores, **pero** solamente servirá para la Actividad android en la que estés.

Uno puede ocupar parcelable, serialize, crear tu propio hash en json, para pode pasar el objeto como tal y no campo por campo. Pero el problema es el mismo.

La manera que yo encontré para poder actualizar mi lista desde otra actividad fue:

**1.** *En tu primera actividad ocupar **startActivityForResult***

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyClassActivity.class);
i.putExtra("myActivity", myActivity);
startActivityForResult(i,1);
```

Donde el primer parámetro es el intento y el segundo es un valor de **petición**, tu le dices a la segunda actividad android, en mi caso,  **MyClassActivity** que tiene una petición con valor 1, este valor debe ser entero y tu lo defines ej: 500, 6600, 2, 3, 4.

**2.** *En tu segunda actividad, recibir el intento como siempre*

```
Intent i = getIntent();
myActivity = i.getExtras().getParcelable("myActivity");
```

**3.** *En mi caso necesitaba devolver o setear el objeto de mi primera actividad, cuando retrocediera con el botón de volver del celular o de la app*

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("IsAccomplished", myActivity.getIsAccomplished());
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Creas un intento, le dices que vas a pasar un valor, en mi caso **IsAccomplished** y le digo que esta OK con **RESULT_OK**

**4.** *Por último recibir la respuesta en tu primera actividad*

```
// This method is called when the second activity finishes
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // check that it is the SecondActivity with an OK result
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            // get String data from Intent
            Integer IsAccomplished = data.getIntExtra("IsAccomplished", 0);

            myActivity.setIsAccomplished(IsAccomplished);
        }
    }
}
```

Resumiendo, **requestCode** es el valor 1 que pasamos en la primera actividad hacia la segunda.
**resultCode**, es el valor de respuesta que le damos.
**data**, tiene todos los valores agregados con putExtra, pueden ser uno o mas o ninguno.

*Para mi problema en particular que yo quería actualizar una imagen en mi lista expandible, en la función **onResume** de mi primera actividad agregue lo siguiente:*

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if( listAdapter != null )
    {
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Con esto le dije, cuando exista el adaptador (se crea en onCreate), al volver de la segunda actividad a la primera (esta queda en background y se reanuda en onResume), le digo con **notifyDataSetChanged**, que si hay un cambio actualice.

*Agregar a tu archivo de manifiesto:*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Ya que en algunas tablets y celulares, intentan acceder a memoria usb ya sea por SDcard u otro dispositivo y si no lo tienes, se cae la app.

Aca la documentación: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

En mi adaptador cuando el campo IsAccomplished = 1, agrega una imagen con un "check", si es 0, agrega una imagen con un círculo SIN "check".

Vi varias soluciones posibles y esta se adapta a mis necesidades, sin tener que estudiar mucho, ocupo funciones que están en android y ademas si por alguna razón el dispositivo donde corra tu app ocupa muchos recursos, si la app necesita liberar memoria u otra cosa, este lo hace automáticamente sin que te arroje algún error, como te podría pasar si quisieras ocupar un modelo estático como "objeto".

**Si alguien quiere aportar mas, con gusto se editara la respuesta y se pueden agregar tips, ya que pase mucho tiempo en esto y no es divertido**

Para mas información pueden revisar buscando en stackoverflow con la palabra "startActivityForResult" y en la documentación de android
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html?hl=es